# How I can make my links in menu close the menu after click on them?

Tags: javascript

I'm a beginner with JavaScript and I'm strugling to make my links in menu acctualy close it after click. I know that the answer may be very simple but yet I can't figure this out ;/

Here is my JavaScript Code:

```
const navSlide = () => {
  const burger = document.querySelector(".burger");
  const nav = document.querySelector(".nav-links");
  const navLinks = document.querySelectorAll(".nav-links li");
  
  burger.addEventListener("click", () => {
    // Toggle Nav
    nav.classList.toggle("nav-active");
    
    // Animate Links
    navLinks.forEach((link, index) => {
      if (link.style.animation) {
        link.style.animation = "";
      } else {
        link.style.animation = `navLinkFade 0.4s ease forwards ${
          index / 9 + 0.4
        }s`;
      }
    });

    // Burger Animation
    burger.classList.toggle("toggle-1");
  });
};

navSlide();
```

Thanks a lot in advance and I appreciate any help you could lend me.

Comment: I can recomment never accessing `.style` - assign CSS behaviour by assigning classes, using `element.classList.add("someclassname")` (or `remove`), and checking whether an element has a particular class using `element.classList.contains("someclass")`. In this case, you need `index` as variable: use CSS variables and set _only_ those using JS.

Comment: Are you looking something like [this](https://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_dropdown_navbar).

Comment: Not exactly, I'm looking for burger menu with on click function that open's up the whole menu with links, and as I wrote in title I want to make links while cilck on them close the whole menu but thank you so much :)

Comment: Thank you so much for edit and all of the tips Mike.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have marked in the code with a comment "NEW LINES" the lines of code I added. I hope this works for you

```
function navSlide() {
    const burger = document.querySelector(".burger");
    const nav = document.querySelector(".nav-links");
    const navLinks = document.querySelectorAll(".nav-links li");

    burger.addEventListener("click", () => {
        //Toggle Nav
        nav.classList.toggle("nav-active");

        //Animate Links
        navLinks.forEach((link, index) => {
            if (link.style.animation) {
                link.style.animation = ""
            } else {
                link.style.animation = `navLinkFade 0.4s ease forwards ${
                  index / 9 + 0.4
                }s`;
            }
        });
        //Burger Animation
        burger.classList.toggle("toggle-1");
    });

    // NEW LINES ----------------------------------
    // Get all "a" tags in ".nav-links" element
    var list_a = nav.getElementsByTagName('a');
    // Add EventListener on all "a" tags in ".nav-links" element
    for (var i = 0; i < list_a.length; i++) {
        list_a[i].addEventListener("click", function () {
            // When click on link script click on burger close link
            burger.click();
        });
    }
    // END NEW LINES ----------------------------------
}

navSlide();
```

Comment: Ohh yes, it works exactly how I wished to. Thank you so much for help, I'm so grateful.